# Nginx reverse proxy with custom headers

Tags: reactjs, http-headers, nginx-reverse-proxy

hope you are well.
I was given a specific project that I'm working for a days and can't figure out how to do this, hope that someone can help.

I have a platform built on React, where users log in and do their stuff. Now, we have a different platform from a different company where we are keeping our internal documentation. From their side we have some custom domain which is public and everyone who get that url can read our docs. That company only provides IP whitelist.

Now, my task is to configure server in order that only my registered users can see that documentation. This is so complicated for me. My idea is to put link somewhere on my platform, and when user click on it to be redirected to documentation without credentials. The idea is to use Nginx proxy server from where will be initiated request. Also, if someone know how to trigger request from server rather that from local computer I'm open to any solution, maybe bypass with script?

So, I've configured proxy but not working as expected, here is config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name docs.mydomain.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/docs.mydomain.com.access.log elk_logs;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/docs.mydomain.com.error.log;

    location / {
        return 301 https://docs.mydomain.com$request_uri;
    }
}


server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name docs.mydomain.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/docs.mydomain.com.bundle.crt; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/docs.mydomain.com.key; # managed by Certbo

  access_log /var/log/nginx/docs.mydomain.com.access.log elk_logs;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/docs.mydomain.com.error.log;

   location / {

        # Preflight requests
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type,Origin,Accept,Authorization,X-Request-With,X-Forwarded-Proto,X-Custom-Proto' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH' always;
            add_header X-Custom-Proto "something" always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 86400;
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }

        if ($request_method ~ '(GET|POST|PATCH|PUT|DELETE)') {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" always;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type,Origin,Accept,Authorization,X-Request-With,X-Forwarded-Proto,X-Custom-Proto' always;
            add_header X-Custom-Proto "something" always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 86400;
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        }
        add_header X-Custom-Proto "something" always;

        proxy_set_header Host docs.othercompany.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade                $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection             "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass https://docs.othercompany.com;

        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type,Origin,Accept,Authorization,X-Request-With,X-Custom-Proto' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH' always;

   }
}
```

Yes, I know, there some duplicated stuff or something that doesn't make any sense, but I don't have that much experience, trying to learn and figure out how to make this working.

I've tried so many different configs and stuff but didn't make it. My idea was to send through React custom header, check it in nginx and if it matches redirect. But no, not working, for example I tried this:

```
if ($http_x_custom_proto != "something") {
            return 500
    }
```

It doesn't matter if I set a variable or just try, not working properly. Requests that I see in Google Inspect network, I can see custom headers in request and response but still whoever I tried If statement to match not working (yeah, I know IF is evil)

Does anyone have idea how to solve this mystery? I can provide more info if you need

Thanks in advance